# No unicode glyphs

Tags: fonts, unicode

I am experiencing trouble displaying unicode glyphs overall in emacs. All unicode glyphs are displayed as boxes with the number for the unicode glyph inside. To best show what I mean, the `M-x list-charset-chars RET unicode-bmp` looks like this:
[image]

I am running GNU emacs version 25.2.1 on a Linux Red Hat distribution through xterm, and locale settings are en_US.UTF-8. When I inspect the font with `M-x describe-font RET` it displays an XLFD:
-misc-fixed-medium-r-semicondensed--13-120-75-75-c-60-iso8859-1
This issue seems to be related to an earlier post which was left unanswered
[Glyphless characters? Never seen before](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/22744/glyphless-characters-never-seen-before)

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I have been struggling with this for some days now.

Thanks!

Comment: were they displayed correctly before? what with a truetype font, dejavu sans mono for example?

Comment: Have you tried using a different font?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Yes, I have tried changing the font, but without success. When emacs loads, it says that it cannot find the specified fonts, although they are available in my ~/.fonts. If I try to set the default font with `M-x set default-font RET`, I only get three different fonts (XLFDs) where one is the one specified above. I suspect it's because I installed emacs with conda, and the conda version cannot find the correct path. However, in emacs version 24.5 my problem is limited to the command line only.